# How to apply yaml file on terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

How do I do this but in terraform using `kubernetes` provider??

```
kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/deploy/kubernetes/overlays/stable/?ref=release-1.4"
```

I have searched for a few, but none mention applying a direct yaml file.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible unless you are willing to type it over to terraform format. However, you could use the `null_resource` to execute that command.

Comment: You could use https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/manifest and `file` and `yamldecode`, but `file` is only for the local filesystem, and so you would probably need some sort of `external_data` since this file is remote. This manifest also appears a better use case for an ad-hoc imperative provision i.e. Ansible and not persistent management i.e. Terraform, and would also be easier that route.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that differently; if that works for you. You want to execute `kubectl` from Terraform, not communicating directly with the Kubernetes API.

I think this method has more advantages than what you originally asking for, because it removes an external dependency.

There's a [`kubectl` provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gavinbunney/kubectl/latest/docs/resources/kubectl_manifest) you can use. You can download the YAML and commit it with your Terraform code. That way it is also easier to review changes to the YAML (between versions).

It would look something like this:

```
resource "kubectl_manifest" "test" {
    yaml_body = <<YAML
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    azure/frontdoor: enabled
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: "Prefix"
        backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 80
YAML
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the [aws-efs-csi-driver Helm Chart](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/tree/master/charts/aws-efs-csi-driver) and further using the [helm terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs).

Would be easy and neat.

```
## refer to the provider documentation to configure accordingly this is the simplest example.
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    config_path = "~/.kube/config"
  }

resource "helm_release" "aws_efs_csi_driver" {
  name       = "aws-efs-csi-driver"

  repository = "https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-efs-csi-driver/"
  chart      = "aws-efs-csi-driver"

  set {
   ### Your custom values ###
  }
}
```